# How to extract the name of a variable in a Python function

Tags: python, function, variable-names

I have a custom Python function that uses the input of a model to create a data frame of the predicted y-values, probabilities, and some other features. I am trying to extract the physical variable name and use it as column within the data frame. In the function the "model" variable signifies a defined model. Is it possible extract the physical string and use it to create a new column?

Below is an extremely basic reproducible example of my code

````
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
import pandas as pd```

df = {'odds_h': [150, 200, -300]}

log_reg = LogisticRegression()

def model_summary(model):
    
    df_summary = pd.DataFrame({'odds_h': df['odds_h'],
                               'model_type': model})
    
    return(df_summary)

model_summary(log_reg)
````

Here is what the data frame output currently displays

[image: current output]

Here is the intended output

[image: desired output]

Comment: What *exactly* is the expected "*physical variable name*"/"*physical string*"? You want to get `"model"`? Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: In the variable within function, I will use defined models such as "log_reg", "gbc", "rf", etc. I would like to call the input directly as text in a column within the data frame. I added in examples above

Comment: See [How to get the original variable name of variable passed to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749796/how-to-get-the-original-variable-name-of-variable-passed-to-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the variable name of the variable passed to the function,here are two simple way.

- get_var_name may give mutiple result if you have a lot variable are same value.
- easy_way maybe a little hard to use,need pass the name of variable.
- dict_way need pass a dict to the function.

Also you can see these link to get more solutions.

[python obtain variable name of argument in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583526/python-obtain-variable-name-of-argument-in-a-function)

[How to get the original variable name of variable passed to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749796/how-to-get-the-original-variable-name-of-variable-passed-to-a-function)

code:

```
def get_var_name(arg):
    return [k for k,v in globals().items() if v == arg]

def easy_way(arg,name):
    #dosomething with arg
    return name

def dict_way(**kwargs):
    for arg_name in kwargs:
        return arg_name

a = 1
b = 1
c = 2
print(get_var_name(a))
print(easy_way(a,"a"))
print(dict_way(a = 1))
```

result:

```
['a', 'b']
a
a
```

Comment: Shouldn't `v == a` be `v is a`?